# Xcode does not remove files from application

Tags: xcode

I am currently working on a game (Mac, Objective-C) that uses prerecorded cutscenes. All the mp4-videofiles are really big. In total I have 86 video files that are 3.77 GB all together. Whenever I build the app it takes well over 15 minutes. Way too long if you are working on just one line of code and you need to test it.

For testing purposes I always deleted the files from the 'Copy Bundle Resources' so that the files would still be in my Xcode project but not in my app. I only included the files that I needed at that moment (so from 3.77 GB to ±100 MB of files). When I built the app then, it was only 40 seconds or so. This has always worked out fine.

However, this week Xcode started acting strange. Even if I removed all of the files in the Copy Bundle Resources all the video files would still be in my application. This means that every time I have to correct a mistake I made, I have to wait 15+ minutes.

After being frustrated for a while I started to remove the files manually (I clicked on Delete -> Move To Trash). So now all the files are removed from the Copy Bundle Resources and out of my Xcode project. But still Xcode includes them in my application if I build it. How?!

So, a long story short, Xcode does not remove files out of my application. The files aren't even in my project anymore but still Xcode finds a way to include them in my application. Does anyone know why/how Xcode does this? Any suggestions/solutions?

Comment: Clean the caches? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4-and-later/6247073#6247073

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up trying to look for answers and I just deleted the build and made a clean one. Right click on the YourApplication.app > Show In Finder > and delete it from there. Then build the app again and it will only contain the files you selected.